# Generate X-Apple-ActionSignature

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, http

for some research at work I have to understand how to generate the X-Apple-ActionSignature which can be found in HTTP-Headers e.g. of iTunes-traffic. I've read that it can be found in other Mac OS X and iOS specific network traffic, too.

What I've found so far is that iTunes sends a GET request to

```
https://init.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZInit.woa/wa/signSapSetupCert
```

In the response a plist is appended which has a key 'sign-sap-setup-cert' containing probably a certificate. After that a POST request contains 'sign-sap-setup-buffer' and is sent to

```
https://play.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZPlay.woa/wa/signSapSetup
```

The response has again 'sign-sap-setup-buffer' in the data segment and after that every other request contains a X-Apple-ActionSignature. However I can not find out how to generate this. Is someone able to help me?

Answer (score 2):

[Looking at this Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/zhengbinham/status/538294206863667200), it seems that "`X-Apple-ActionSignature`" is some kind of proprietary signature or metrics posts generated and/or used by FairPlay.

It's not something that Apple has documented publicly, nor do they make it easy to figure out how to generate or spoof (even if for non-malicious purposes like research).

Your best bet is to contact Apple directly (e.g. via a Technical Support Incident or TSI) and tell them *exactly* what you are doing and the big picture of why you are doing this, and if you are lucky the Developer Technical Support person will connect up with the right people in Apple Engineering to give you the answers you need.

Comment: Thx for this suggestion, maybe I should give it a try.

Comment: JFYI: Get response from Apple but they won't disclose it. Therefore only reversing the AppStore or iTunes could help :)